# Почему перечисление строк CSV файла невозможно без предварительного указания файла и создания объекта reader, даже если ранее они были созданы

Tags: python, csv, for

Мой код не отображает перечисление строк из CSV-файла без повторного указания на файл и создания объекта reader.

```
import csv
CSV_file = open('01.example.csv')
print(type(CSV_file))        #<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

CSV_file_reader = csv.reader(CSV_file)
print(type(CSV_file_reader)) #<class '_csv.reader'>

CSV_file_data = list(CSV_file_reader)
print(type(CSV_file_data))   #<class 'list'>
print(CSV_file_data)         #список списков

###CSV_file = open('01.example.csv')
###CSV_file_reader = csv.reader(CSV_file)
for row in CSV_file_reader:
    print(row)
```

не раскомментировав - работать не будет, хотя подобные строчки есть выше.

Полагаю, причина в строке `CSV_file_data = list(CSV_file_reader)`, но она не меняет переменную, а лишь интерпретирует её как список, так ведь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Полагаю, причина в строке `CSV_file_data = list(CSV_file_reader)`, но она не меняет переменную, а лишь интерпретирует её как список, так ведь?

Нет, эта строка **итерирует** объект `CSV_file_reader`, после чего его уже нельзя итерировать ещё раз в цикле `for`.